# angular dynamically assign template

Tags: angular, youtube-javascript-api

I need to use the youtube player from @angular/youtube-player but I need the videoId to be dynamic. Is it possible to assign variables to the component decorator?

I have tried this but I get an error:

```js
const videoId = localStorage.setItem('videoId}', welcomeInfo.imageVideoUrl);

@Component({
  template: `<youtube-player
    videoId=${videoId}
    suggestedQuality="highres"
    [height]="600"
    [width]="1080"
    [startSeconds]="43"
    [endSeconds]="60">
  </youtube-player>`,
  selector: 'app-video'
})
```

Comment: `videoId` is an `@Input()` so you can just do `[videoId]="videoId"`. It would help though if you said what error you get, and if you could provide a minimal reproduction of your issue on stackblitz

Comment: this worked perfectly! if you want post it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To dynamically assign a videoId to the `youtube-player` you can do:

```
@Component({
  template: `<youtube-player
    [videoId]="videoId"
    suggestedQuality="highres"
    [height]="600"
    [width]="1080"
    [startSeconds]="43"
    [endSeconds]="60">
  </youtube-player>`,
  selector: 'app-video'
})
```